# Run a vbscript as an admin from itself (Nagios / NSclient)

Tags: vbscript, file-permissions, nagios, user-permissions

I'll detail as much as I can so you can understand in which environment I'm working on and what I am trying to do.

I am using Nagios at work to monitor our servers. Each one of our Windows servers has NSclient++ installed on it. One of the many scripts Nagios' calling is check_updates.vbs; here 's how it goes if someone need to know:

On the Nagios' server side, we execute the following command:

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H WindowsServerIpAddress -p 5666 -t 120 -c check_updates
```

When we execute that command, here is what's happening on the Windows Server:

By using the *nscp* service, it calls the following command, defined in the nsclient.ini file (into NSclient++ folder):

```
check_updates=cscript.exe //T:120 //NoLogo scripts\\check_updates.vbs
```

Then, it calls the [check_updates.vbs script](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw-mxuBLNZDublJ5bDd0ZkN2UEk/edit?usp=sharing).

---

The local account on the Windows Server is the administrator one. We have changed nscp service's properties so that this service is called with another account, created especially for monitoring.

So, when we call the check_updates.vbs script directly on the Windows server (i.e locally), everything goes well, the script is working perfectly. But if we call it remotely, on the Nagios server, we have a simple (but deadly) error that says *Permission denied*.

That is why we are focusing on giving enough permissions to the monitoring-user.

After searching more and more and trying everything we could, I must say we're kinda lost right now.

The last solution I tried was to add these lines at the beginning of the script, to give the monitoring-user enough permissions to execute the script properly:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
If WScript.Arguments.length = 0 Then
  Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  ObjShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & _
  WScript.ScriptFullName & """" &_
  " RunAsAdministrator", , "runas", 1
End if
```

(I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466681/how-to-run-vbs-as-administrator-from-vbs))

When I use this, locally I get an [error notice*] but the script is working anyway. However, when I call the script remotely, I just have a timeout after 120s.

More info: UAC is disabled on the Windows server, and the monitoring-user has full access control on the NSclient++\scripts folder. Using the nscp service with the admin account is not the solution we are seeking for this matter.

So, am I missing something here ? Do you have any idea about this ?

Thanks for the help ! :)

[*error notice]: Invalid arguments, check help with cscript.exe check_available_updates.vbs -h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer Tony, I've tried your suggestions, but eventually we ended up getting around the problem.

Despite we gave the monitoring-user all permissions needed to execute this script, it was not working. So here's what we've done:

We created a bat file which contains the command-line to call check_update.vbs and to write its output into a new file:

```
cscript.exe //T:120 //NoLogo "C:\Program Files\NSClient++\scripts\check_updates.vbs" > "C:\Program Files\NSClient++\check_update.log"
```

Then, we've created a scheduled task (using the TaskScheduler) which calls the bat file every day to check for new updates.

To have the correct output in Nagios, we created another vbscript which only has to read the check_update.log file and return the appropriate value to Nagios:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const rOK = 0
Const rWarning = 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Program Files\NSClient++\check_update.log", ForReading)

FirstChar = objFile.Read(1)
Content = objFile.ReadAll

If FirstChar = "O" Then
Wscript.Echo FirstChar + Content
Wscript.Quit(rOK)
Else
WScript.Echo FirstChar + Content
End If
Wscript.Quit(rWarning)
```

This vbscript is **really** basic, since it only reads the first letter of the file to decide which value to return. Indeed, if there are no updates available, the message will always be "OK - No patches missing".

So, by calling the bat file using the SchedulerTask, we get around the fact that the monitoring-user has not enough permissions to execute the script.

Answer (score 0):

If UAC is off then it's not a UAC permission error therefore don't worry about runas.

It's also unlikely to be a file permissions problem (all admins are equal unless someone made it different).

What is likely is the different environments. You have an assumption that is true for the interactive user only. You need to log what is happening in your script (see wshshell.LogEvent(intType, strMessage [,strTarget])). If your script has

```
on error remove next
```

remove it.

Mapped drives are a problem. As are environmental variables and special folders.

Try using Runas command line command with various options (eg /env) to see if you can duplicate the behaviour.

Also run

```
cmd /c set > c:\set.log
```

and compare the output from the two ways of running it (ie with your client and direct).