# Run quser from outlook macro, without admin rights

Tags: vba, outlook

From an Outlook macro, I want to run the quser command to get the logon datetime :

```
Private Sub getLogonDateTime()

    MsgBox CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("quser").StdOut.ReadAll()

End Sub
```

It works when I'm logged in as admin.
When I'm not logged in as admin, I get a runtime error ("file not found").

But quser works in cmd or powershell even if I'm not admin.

Is it some kind of security setting ?
How can I read quser result from outlook VBA if I'm not an admin ?

Comment: Those may be a interesting : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17467283/4628637 and https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/310e57f9-2367-4293-9f97-53d0e077aacc/vb-script-to-run-a-batch-script-as-admin?forum=ITCG