# Run Wscript.Shell Object to call Administrative Command Prompt for PsExec

Tags: cmd, vbscript, uac, psexec

I'm trying to call `PsExec` from a `WScript.Shell` Object in the form posted below (but am definitely open to alternatives).

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "cmd.exe /C C:\Users\NOT_Administrator\Desktop\PsExec.exe \\192.168.10.5  -u Administrator -p PASSWORD cmd /c ""C:\Windows\Launch_Bat.exe"""
```

Please note that for `PsExec` to ever succeed a PASSWORD is required.

The thing about this is that because the initial `cmd.exe` from `oShell.Run` is being launched from a non-administrative user, `PsExec` inherits those lack of privileges and ultimately fails to connect giving the error "Access is Denied." I concluded this after reading and testing `PsExec` between a non-administrative command prompt (no VBScript involved) in which it failed, and from an administrative Command Prompt from where it succeeded.

So my question is, is it possible to make VBScript launch either `cmd.exe` as an Administrator (preferably in the form posted above) natively within the script, or force the `PsExec` portion to use the priviliges passed in as administrative account credentials?

Additionally, I tried 2 methods posted below (both are in a different form from the one I desire):

1. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/9bda53d7-ec2e-4bc2-8e97-4487233bc55b

   ```
   set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   PASSW = "PASSWORD"
   WshShell.run "runas /user:Administrator %comspec%"
   WScript.Sleep 1000
   WshShell.SendKeys PASSW
   WScript.Sleep 1000
   WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
   ```

   But this closed then opened up an administrative Command Prompt, but I couldn't make the script pass anything into the new prompt.
2. https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/windows-7/windows-7-run-vbs-script-as-elevated-user-uac/

   ```
   If WScript.Arguments.Length = 0 Then
       Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
       objShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", Chr(34) & _
           WScript.ScriptFullName & Chr(34) & " uac", "", "runas", 1
   Else
       WScript.Echo "This code is ran as an elevated user, ie. 'Administrator'"
   End If
   ```

   But this opens up an echo dialog box, but when I put it at the head of my script, it simply made it loop infinitely. It also requires me to input the password which I do not mind. I prefer not to, but if I must I will. I know that `runas` doesn't have an explicit flag to pass in the password unfortunately although you can use set_credentials.

Comment: `WshShell.run "runas /user:Administrator %comspec% any other parameters you want"`

Comment: Yea, I mentioned this above. For some reason this method wouldn't allow the script to pass anything into the newly opened command prompt. Thanks for the pointer though.

Comment: Type `cmd /?` to see why. Your command is misformed. You have to use /k or /c. You could use WMIC (or WMI from any COM language like VBScript). `wmic /node:127.0.0.1 /user:user /password:password process call create "c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c c:\\mybat.bat"`. Windows Scripting Host has remote script execution as well. Windows Shell Objeects can run a command elevated using RunAs verb from right click menu.

Comment: PS WMIC due to the fact it initialises on first run, requires an ADMIN to run it at least once before limited users can run it.

Comment: Plus if you say what your batch file is doing there is likely a way to do it from 1 machine using WMIC.

Comment: Honestly, I've been trying to avoid WMIC because it's very finicky. With regards to the command being malformed, which one are you referring to? The one whose form is my preference, or the first alternate method, or the second alternate method? When I changed the first alternate to the following ...WshShell.run "runas /user:Administrator cmd.exe /c ""C:\Windows\Launch_Bat.exe"""...  That failed.   Additionally, when I did ...WshShell.run "runas /user:Administrator cmd.exe"   then tried to use SendKeys to push this into the new prompt that failed.

Comment: Following up, if you did mean that the initial one which is my preference is misformed, it isn't, but in retrospect I should have been more clear. PSEXEC launches, but I get an "Access is Denied" message because it is not launched from an Administrative prompt. Additionally, the batch file is really just for show. It could have been a text file, but the administrative PSEXEC launch has to be done from the native VBS script.

Comment: *Be aware that runas does not provide the ability to launch an application with an elevated access token, regardless of whether it is a standard user with privileges like a Backup Operator or an administrator. The runas command grants the user the ability to launch an application with different credentials. ... If your program programmatically uses the runas command, ensure that it is not intended to launch an elevated process.*
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756922.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: The last sample is what you should use for re-running a VBScript with elevated privileges. However, you cannot simply prepend your code with that, because whoever wrote that snippet put the code to run with elevated privileges in the `Else` branch instead of [exiting from the (original) script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17467283/1630171) after re-running it.

Comment: Sorry guys. A string of bad luck (computer crash and having to get my car fixed twice in 3 days held me up). Ansgar, I will try your suggestion, but I think the most appropriate one may be changing the Registry.