# mkdir in batch file as admin

Tags: batch-file, runas, iexpress

I'm trying to write a batch file that creates a new directory in `%programfiles%`. It needs to be run as admin. I've tried:

```
runas /user:admin-pc\admin "mkdir C:\Program Files\MyDir"
runas /user:admin-pc\admin "mkdir \"C:\Program Files\MyDir\""
runas /user:admin-pc\admin "cmd /c mkdir \"C:\Program Files\MyDir\""
runas /user:admin-pc\admin "cmd /c mkdir %programfiles%\MyDir"
runas /user:admin-pc\admin "cmd /c mkdir \"C:/Program Files/MyDir\""
runas /user:admin-pc\admin "cmd /c mkdir C:\Program^ Files\MyDir"
```

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Don't use the `runas` command - elevate the command shell first, then make the directories. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: It's the install script for an IExpress installer. So it can't involve the user clicking "Run as administrator."

Comment: Your installer must request elevation. You can't bypass that. This is not a question for stackoverflow.

Comment: IExpress, which comes pre-installed in Win7, doesn't request elevation during installation. Are you saying that runas has no use whatsoever?

Comment: RunAs can't elevate but can only change user as a non admin.

Comment: Be aware that runas does not provide the ability to launch an application with an elevated access token, regardless of whether it is a standard user with privileges like a Backup Operator or an administrator. The runas command grants the user the ability to launch an application with different credentials. ... If your program programmatically uses the runas command, ensure that it is not intended to launch an elevated process. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530410.aspx

Comment: You cam make your IExpress installer and use ResHacker to replace it's manifest with the one in my answer. http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker It's Resource type 24.

Comment: Wow. I never would have believed it. Worked like a charm! Opened it in ResHacker, changed RequestedExecutionLevel in the manifest to level=
"requireAdministrator" in ResHacker and saved. Zero defects. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question turned out to be IExpress specific.

You cam make your IExpress installer and use ResHacker to replace it's manifest with the one in my answer. http://angusj.com/resourcehacker It's Resource type 24.

> Wow. I never would have believed it. Worked like a charm! Opened it in
>   ResHacker, changed RequestedExecutionLevel in the manifest to level=
>   "requireAdministrator" in ResHacker and saved. Zero defects. Thanks

This answer is console programs specific - see [Run batch script as admin during Maven build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47902221/run-batch-script-as-admin-during-maven-build/47913331#47913331) for a more generic way.

To elevate in Windows the recommended way is by embedding a manifest. Which can't be done for text based programs. It's easy to put vbscript into VB.NET, add a manifest, and compile it.

Current scripting approaches mimic a right click and then Run As Administrator. This only works if file associations are Windows' defaults, eg the user can stop this approach from working by customising their system.

> Be aware that runas does not provide the ability to launch an
>   application with an elevated access token, regardless of whether it is
>   a standard user with privileges like a Backup Operator or an
>   administrator. The runas command grants the user the ability to launch
>   an application with different credentials. ... If your program
>   programmatically uses the runas command, ensure that it is not
>   intended to launch an elevated process.
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530410.aspx

To use

```
 RunAsAdminConsole <CMD Command Line>
```

EG

```
 RunAsAdminConsole mkdir "C:\Program Files\MyDir"
```

The files. Place each file on the desktop. The must be ANSI. Change this line from `/k` to `/c` as you prefer `Shell("cmd /k " & Command())`

**RunAsAdminConsole.vb**

```
imports System.Runtime.InteropServices 
Public Module MyApplication  
    Public Sub Main ()
        Dim wshshell as object
        WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Shell("cmd /k " & Command())
    End Sub 
End Module
```

**RunAsAdmin.Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity
    version="1.0.0.0"
    processorArchitecture="*"
    name="Color Management"
    type="win32"
/>
<description>RunAsAdminConsole</description>
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2"> 
<security> 
    <requestedPrivileges> 
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/> 
    </requestedPrivileges> 
</security> 
</trustInfo> 

</assembly>
```

And the batch file **RunAsAdminConsole.bat** to compile above

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc "%userprofile%\Desktop\RunAsAdminconsole.vb" /win32manifest:"%userprofile%\Desktop\RunAsAdmin.manifest" /out:"%userprofile%\Desktop\RunAsAdminConsole.exe" /target:exe
```

A file called **RunAsAdminConsole.exe** will appear on the desktop.