# Run program from bat file with admin auto prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, uac

i have a simple bat file with the following.....

```
10th-f-Downsampling.exe --max_old_space_size=3500
```

the extra command line runs the program that has been compiled in nexe to allocate extra memory.

what i am trying to do is to run the program ( and its associated command line ) to "run as administrator" from the bat file so i don't have to edit properties.

There is an option in windows if you right click/properties/compatibility/"run as administrator" but i want to factor that into the bat file.  yes i know it will prompt in the same way and that's fine , i am just trying to automate this so people don't have to right click and change the program.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47902221/run-batch-script-as-admin-during-maven-build/47913331#47913331 and see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895544/mkdir-in-batch-file-as-admin/47896026#47896026 on how to edit your program.

Comment: Possibly required in every computer virus?