# Sudo -l Windows equivalent

Tags: windows, cmd

There's some equivalent in Windows to sudo -l. I know that the equivalent is runas but I need to see all the things that can be done as admin. Thank you

PD: I have to run it from the CMD.

Comment: There is no sudo in Windows. `Runas` is not the same.

Comment: See my answer here to make your own sudo. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895544/mkdir-in-batch-file-as-admin/47896026#47896026

Comment: Try my [wsudo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54642324/1768303).

Answer (score 1):

From the command line, you can use the following option:

```
runas /showtrustlevels
```

I think this could be somehow comparable to `sudo -l` on Linux.

This [runas command reference page](https://ss64.com/nt/runas.html) contains some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the `CMD.exe` and right click it, then click "Run as Administrator".
There is a example for Windows 10:

[image: here] ,

and a example for Windows 7:

[image: here].

Comment: No, the answer is wrong. @elvaqueroloconivel1 said he had to RUN it FROM CMD!

Comment: To run things as a admin in windows, there is no equivalent to sudo. You have to run as administrator or do what this says https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895544/mkdir-in-batch-file-as-admin/47896026#47896026 `runas` is not a equivalent to sudo

Comment: So, just say this. Everyone knows how to open a program as admin!

Comment: You may never know. Some people who are new to windows might not.

Comment: A simple search in the internet can really help. They must not be lazy.